# Images' site don't loading with a specific url in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and I try to create a personal blog!

I have a problem with an url that it has to show all post wrote in a specific year and specific month.

My url is look like(http://localhost:2282/Blog/Archive/2010/5).

So... it work correctly, infact it show all record that have year=2010 and month=5 but my problem is that when I use this url, images in total my site are no longer loading.

I have this problem only with this url's type.

I think that the problem maybe is my maproute?

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         "ArchiveRoute",
         "Blog/Archive/{anno}/{mese}",
         new { controller = "Blog", Action = "Archive",anno = @"\d{4}", mese = @"\d{2}" }     
      );
```

Why images don't loading with this url?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your View may be referencing images using a relative path that doesn't work based on your current route. URLs you use in your view need to be relative to the resulting action's URL, not the folder where the view is stored.

You could use an absolute path or use `<img src="<%=Url.Content("~/images")%>/image.jpg" alt="" />` (replace "~/images" with the path to your images, where "~/" equals the root of your application).

If you're using a Master page, it too should be careful to use something like `Url.Content`, because the Master can get used by different views that are accessible by different URLs!

Comment: Greeeaatttt!! you're number 1! Thanks. Without you, I won't be able to do! :)